Files.write slow on Windows Surface
I have a simple Java 17 method, that writes content to a specified path. The content is not long, just around 1kb.
It in general works as expected, but on a specific device, a Windows 11 Surface Pro 7, this write operation can take 5-10 seconds!
Path path = Paths.get(file);
Files.createDirectories(path.getParent());
try {
  byte[] bytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(data.getBytes());
  Files.write(path, bytes);
} catch /* ... */

It seems it gets slowed down by accessing the file system of that device.

What could be the reason for that?
What actions could be done to increase the file system access?

Edit:
Added output form winsat
C:\Windows\System32>winsat disk -drive c
Windows-Systembewertungstool
> Wird ausgeführt: Featureaufzählung ''
> Laufzeit 00:00:00.00
> Wird ausgeführt: Speicherbewertung '-drive c -ran -read'
> Laufzeit 00:00:00.67
> Wird ausgeführt: Speicherbewertung '-drive c -seq -read'
> Laufzeit 00:00:02.78
> Wird ausgeführt: Speicherbewertung '-drive c -seq -write'
> Laufzeit 00:00:02.13
> Wird ausgeführt: Speicherbewertung '-drive c -flush -seq'
> Laufzeit 00:00:00.77
> Wird ausgeführt: Speicherbewertung '-drive c -flush -ran'
> Laufzeit 00:00:00.72
> Dshow-Videocodierzeit                        0.00000 s
> Dshow-Videodecodierzeit                      0.00000 s
> Media Foundation-Decodierzeit                0.00000 s
> Disk  Random 16.0 Read                       142.87 MB/s          7.4
> Disk  Sequential 64.0 Read                   1747.81 MB/s          8.9
> Disk  Sequential 64.0 Write                  902.61 MB/s          8.4
> Durchschnittliche Lesezeit mit sequenziellen Schreibvorgängen0.232 ms          8.5
> Latenz: 95. Perzentil                        0.398 ms          8.7
> Latenz: Maximum                              8.509 ms          8.1
> Durchschnittliche Lesezeit bei zufallsgesteuerten Schreibvorgängen0.224 ms          8.9
> Gesamtausführungszeit 00:00:07.42


You sure this isn't a hardware problem. Have you run Windows built-in benchmark (e.g. winsat disk -drive c to benchmark the C: drive)? Run it from an administrator command prompt. I suspect your sequential writes will be very low.

@Mark Yes, that is true. It resulted in 00:00:02xxx values for -seq write and -seq read

The more interesting thing is the Disk  Sequential 64.0 Write and Latency: ... outputs

@MarkRotteveel I added the output in the question.

Those stats seems to be OK, so I guess that is not the issue then. Though random reads seem to be a bit low for an SSD.

What type is data btw?

@g00se it is a base64 string

Then all you need is Files.write(path, Base64.getDecoder().decode(data));

Excuse me to ask, how will this increase the performance of the file system access on that surface pro device? Kindly stick to the topic as it is productive code I can't change  because it is shorter or something.

It won't. It's just a suggestion, which you can ignore if you want

Have you checked if it might be the anti-malware checkers causing the delay by taking a long time to check the content of the file you're trying to write?

@k314159 Yes. The mentioned device is pretty virgin it only has browsers, anydesk and openvpn installed along with the application of interest. No 3rd party checkers or something. I tried to alter several windows owned security settings here, but got no success.

Are you able to try it on another Surface Pro with identical hardware and identically configured, just to check it's not a hardware problem?

@k314159 Unfortunately no, this is the only Surface available for me and I am not in knowledge if there are any other Surfaces with the app of interest out there. It could be that this is the only one.

Surface Pro 7 has had it's major issues with performance. See https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/forum/all/surface-pro-7-cpu-stuck-at-low-clock-speed/f2924352-eff4-41a7-b4e1-030e5ae9d111
Disk read/write seems ok.

@TomCools Thank you for the link, it looked real promising. Sadly it didn't change anything. If this was an SO answer I would still upvote it at least.

I had two instances of desktop computer SSDs in the last two years, in which slowly but surely the SSD became slower and slower, until in task manager under "Leistung > Datenträger" (you seem to be German) I saw that the SSD was always 100% in use, even though the PC was idle. Everything was slow from boot to everyday work. The reason was the same in both cases: SSDs going defective in need of exchange. Cloned both SSDs onto new ones, and the system was a fast as on day 1 again. Cloning can take time due to the worn out SSD, though, so you need to be patient. Surface Pro 7 is from 2019, right?

can be related to some configuration, eclipse had similar issue before I would suggest test a C# program to see if thats also writing slow or build with graalvm and see if that helps.

I suspect it can happen based on JDK vendor. Are you using Oracle's JDK? Can you try with Azul JDK. It's free. It's light weight and fast. You can compare the same write code based on different JDK vendor's performance.

To which location is the content written? And from which location does it come? Are you writing on a slower medium, like a sd card or something like that?

This is unlikely to be a problem that is Java specific.  Your example is simply create and writing a file.   While there is some work in this like:
byte[] bytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(data.getBytes());

that is all well-optimized code, and it won't depend on the platform in any significant way.  It will take milliseconds at most.
The code where the time is being spent will be these lines:
Files.createDirectories(path.getParent());

and
Files.write(path, bytes);

But the vast majority of time taken for those two lines will be consumed in the operating system.

From other peoples comments, there are a couple of plausible theories about what could be going on:

Your SSD is dying and the OS is struggling to get disk writes to succeed.  (The problem could be only for specific SSD disk blocks; e.g. the blocks that hold the metadata for the directory you are creating the file in.  They may not show up in a disk performance test.)

Something else on the system is interfering; e.g. anti-virus software.


Your comment seems to support this.

The code works fine and fast on all devices. The only slow device is that single one. No exceptions occur, they are all catched. It is a performance issue only.


Anish B. wrote

The issue could be the JDK that you are using from a specific vendor which is not able to use the system architecture properly and might be causing the latency.

As far as I am aware, all vendors for Java on Windows started with the OpenJDK codebase.  It is hard to see how they could have gotten basic file I/O to perform so poorly, let alone to have not have picked this up in testing.  IMO, changing Java vendors would be a waste of time.
And as far as Java (hypothetically) needing to do something special to make file I/O fast on the platform, it is really the host operating system's job to do that.  It is hard to see how the Java runtime could do anything about it ... if the operating system itself can't.

Open Settings > System > Storage
Click on "Storage Sense" or "Configure Storage Sense or run it now"
Scroll down and click "Run Storage Sense now"
This will run various storage optimizations.
Try this and see if it improves performance.
You can also use BufferedOutputStream in your program and see if it improves performance.
